# using recompose, how overwrite mapped prop from state, with regular prop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, recompose

Building simple phone input form component:

```
class PhoneSettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {changePhoneInput, submitPhone, errorText, loading} = this.props
            return (
                <View>
                    <TextInput onChangeText={changePhoneInput}/>
                        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{errorText}</Text>
                        <Button
                            onPress={submitPhone}
                        />
                        {loading && <Spinner/>}
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

when user types the phone in field, this function updates `errorText` prop:

```
const changePhoneInput = props => phone => {
    const {setPhone, setErrorText} = props
    setPhone(phone)
    let error = /[0-9]{6,9}/g.test(phone) ? '' : "Please enter valid number";
    setErrorText(error)
};
```

component is enhanced with this code, and you can see `errorText` prop is coming from redux state as well:

```
const enhance = compose(
    withState('errorText', 'setErrorText', ''),
    connect((state, nextOwnProps) => {
        state = state.get('settings')
        return {
            loading: state.get('loading'),
            errorText: state.get('error')
        }
    }, {
        submitPhoneAction
    }),
    withState('phone', 'setPhone', ''),
    withHandlers({
        changePhoneInput,
        submitPhone
    }),
)
```

When user clicks button, and network request failed, from reducer I receive error which I map then to a component as an `errorText` prop. But when user edits phone again, "Please enter valid number" error should show up, but prop from redux remains, and my `changePhoneInput` doesnt update the prop. How to avoid this ?

I tried to change positions of functions in compose, it didn't helped. what I basically need is to overwrite `errorText` prop in my component with `changePhoneInput` function. Of course I can use another variable name but I think there should be another way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the store state in `connect`

```
const enhance = compose(
    withState('errorText', 'setErrorText', ''),
    connect((state, nextOwnProps) => {
        state = state.get('settings')
        return {
            loading: state.get('loading'),

            // You can override the store state here, ex:
            errorText: nextOwnProps.errorText || state.get('error')

        }
    }, {
        submitPhoneAction
    }),
    withState('phone', 'setPhone', ''),
    withHandlers({
        changePhoneInput,
        submitPhone
    }),
)
```

However, I recommend you to take a look at [`withStateHandlers`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstatehandlers), which can combine `withState` and `withHandlers` into one HOC.